# action after a delay

Tags: jquery

I have a problem with this jquery script.

```
toggle:function()
{
 if(this.opened){
   $("slideToBuyBottomBtnClosed").setStyle("display","block");
   $("slideToBuyBottomBtnOpen").setStyle("display","none");
   $("sildeToBuyContent").setStyle("overflow","hidden");
   this.openOrCloseEffect.start({height:0});
   this.opened=false
 }else{
   $("slideToBuyBottomBtnClosed").setStyle("display","none");
   $("slideToBuyBottomBtnOpen").setStyle("display","block");
   setTimeout($("sildeToBuyContent").setStyle("overflow","visible"), 1000);
   this.openOrCloseEffect.start({height:182}); 
   this.opened=true
 }
}
```

I'm fighting with the `setTimeout` - I need to have this line:

```
$("sildeToBuyContent").setStyle("overflow","visible");
```

started with a 1 second delay but I don't know if `setTimeout` is the right way.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to pass a function as the first argument to `setTimeout`. Change

```
setTimeout($("sildeToBuyContent").setStyle("overflow","visible"), 1000);
```

to

```
setTimeout(function () { $("sildeToBuyContent").setStyle("overflow","visible") }, 1000);
```

This will change the `overflow` of the element after 1 second.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you - you helped me out with a problem i was fighting with for over a day :D

Comment: Hello Emil,
sorry for bothering u again but can u tell whay this action does not work:

$("ul.sf-menu li").mouseover(function(){$("sildeToBuyContentWindow").css("overflow","visible");});

i really have no clue!

Comment: slideToBuyConentWindow needs a selector

Comment: Htdrawn said it. You probably meant `#slideToBuyConentWindow`.

Comment: i tried it with #slideToBuyConentWindow but did not work. I really have no idea where the problem is

Answer (score 2):

There's a few things wrong here.

1. `$('slideToBuyBottomBtnClosed')` will be trying to find all elements with that as their tag name, that is `<slideToBuyBottomBtnClosed>` elements. You probably want to use a hash at the start to select by id, or a dot to select by class name, depending on your code.
2. There's a couple of typos (sildeToBuyContent)
3. Coming to the actual issue with timeouts, the problem is on this line:

   `setTimeout($("sildeToBuyContent").setStyle("overflow","visible"), 1000)`

When it comes to here, it will evaluate the contents of the brackets before passing them to the `setTimeout` function, just as it would if you typed `function(3 + 2)`. If you want that to run after one second, you can pass it an actual function like this:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $('#slideToBuyContent').setStyle("overflow", "visible");
}, 1000);
```

or as a string to be evaluated (though this is much messier in my opinion);

```
setTimeout("$('#slideToBuyContent').setStyle('overflow', 'visible')", 1000);
```

There's also this method, which probably won't work in your situation, but it would save you creating another anonymous function:

```
setTimeout($('#slideToBuyContent').setStyle, 1000, 'overflow', 'visible');
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [Timers Plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/timers).

Answer (score 0):

first argument to [setTimeout()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout) is a function or a string of code, so try:

```
setTimeout('$("sildeToBuyContent").setStyle("overflow","visible")', 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your help. You helped me a lot.

i dont wanna bother you but do you guys have an idea for this action why it wont work :(

```
$("ul.sf-menu li").mouseover(function(){
   $("#sildeToBuyContentWindow").css("overflow","visible");
});
```

i want that by mouseover of all < li> in < ul class="sf.menu"> - also the < li> in the second an third level of the < ul class="sf.menu"> the overflow of the element with the ID #sildeToBuyContentWindow changes to visible.

this was the originals code i used to bild my action but without success.

```
$(document).ready(
  function(){
    $( '#switches li' ).mouseover(
      function(){
        $( "#slides div" ).hide();
        $( '#switches li' ).css( 'font-weight', 'normal' );
        $( this ).css( 'font-weight', 'bold' );
        $( '#slide' + $( this ).attr( 'id' ).replace( 'switch', '' ) ).show();
      }
    );
  }
);
```